# The controller with the name '' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm using AngularJs 1.6.9 with ASP.NET Core 2. 
The error is

> The controller with the name 'pag1Controller' is not registered.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/css/ngDialog-master/css/ngDialog.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/css/ngDialog-master/css/ngDialog-theme-default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="~/lib/angular-1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/ngDialog-master/js/ngDialog.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular-1.6.9/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app/app.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="" ng-app="MyApp">

    <div id="wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label">Pag:</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                            <li><a href="#!/Pag1">Pag1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                            <li><a href="#!/Pag2">Pag2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
                @RenderBody()
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div ng-view>

</div>

<div ng-controller="homeController">
    {{Message}}
</div>

<script src="~/js/app/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngCookies', 'ngDialog', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    config.baseURL = "http://localhost/";

    $routeProvider.when('/Pag1', {

        templateUrl: config.baseURL + "Pag1/Index",
        controller: 'pag1Controller'

    })

    $routeProvider.when('/Pag2', {
        templateUrl: config.baseURL + "Pag2/Index",
        controller: 'pag2Controller'
    })
});
```

pag1.cshtml

```
<div ng-controller="pag1Controller">

    Pag1

    <button ng-click="onMensaje()">View alert</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">
        <h1>Template heading</h1>
        <p>Content goes here</p>
    </script>

</div>

<script src="~/js/app/controllers/pag1Controller/pag1Controller.js"></script>
```

pag1Controller.js:

```
app.controller('pag1Controller', function ($scope, ngDialog) {

    $scope.onMensaje = function () {

        ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId' });

    };
});
```

[image]

Comment: Reference to the controller's file is missing within the main html page.

Comment: Hello, yes if I put the <script src="~/js/app/controllers/pag1Controller/pag1Controller.js"></script> on the home.cshtml works, but It means that I have tu put all the files controllers js

Comment: And how do you expect the browser to know where to take your js from? You have two choices: (1) maintain one file for each controller and include a reference (i.e. `<script...`) for each of them within your main, or (2) keep all your controllers within a single file and have one and only one reference within your main. The down side of the second is that, as of a certain moment, you will be editing a HUGE file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the controller in the index.html file , so that controller gets registered when app loads,

```
 <script src="~/js/app/app.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/app/controllers/pag1Controller/pag1Controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the issue there?

Comment: Read the question!! I don't know why that is happening!

Comment: but you need to put all .js files on your home page. you are loading the page with a lot of code, that is not necessary at the moment. I wonder I could load the controller js, that I only use at the moment when the page is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Import that controller in your `index.html` file.

```
<script srs=".../pag1Controller"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, yes if I put the <script src="~/js/app/controllers/pag1Controller/pag1Controller.js"></script> on the home.cshtml works, 
it means that I have to loaded all controllers js files, even if the controller is not used, it does not sound very performant. 
Is there another solution, the only way is to load all the .js controllers before using them?

Comment: Yes, you can use `gulp` to do that for you. Read more about on.